# Delphi XE 5 TAdsTable Random EAccessViolation on OnCalcFields

Tags: delphi, dataset, access-violation, advantage-database-server

I'm getting a random access violation at a few clients sites
its happening a few times a week in several different screens and only some clients are effected

we are using Advantage components version 10.10.0.51 (ACE 10.10)

Seems to be the OnCalcFields that is having this issue

I haven't been able to reproduce the issue but have captured the error using Mad Except

```
compiled with      : Delphi XE5
madExcept version  : 4.0.18
callstack crc      : $e2a61555, $1dade52a, $1dade52a
exception number   : 1
exception class    : EAccessViolation
exception message  : Access violation at address 00406C87 in module 'myExe.exe'. Read of address 0C5E001B.

main thread ($22bc):
00406c87 +0067 myExe.exe System           728    +0 Move
007619c9 +030d myExe.exe adsdata                    TAdsDataSet.SetFieldData
007237de +003a myExe.exe Data.DB                    TDataSet.SetFieldData
00711b9b +009f myExe.exe Data.DB                    TField.SetData
007130f3 +00a3 myExe.exe Data.DB                    TStringField.SetAsAnsiString
00713027 +002f myExe.exe Data.DB                    TStringField.SetAsString
01e65510 +0130 myExe.exe DOrder         20432    +8 TfrmDOrder.tbDebtorCalcFields
00726d09 +0015 myExe.exe Data.DB                    TDataSet.DoOnCalcFields
0072541c +0060 myExe.exe Data.DB                    TDataSet.CalculateFields
00725380 +0048 myExe.exe Data.DB                    TDataSet.GetCalcFields
0072532e +0002 myExe.exe Data.DB                    TDataSet.GetCalcFields
0075f05a +019a myExe.exe adsdata                    TAdsDataSet.GetCurTranslatedRecord
0075f1d0 +0088 myExe.exe adsdata                    TAdsDataSet.GetRecord
00724f95 +0031 myExe.exe Data.DB                    TDataSet.GetPriorRecord
0072513b +0157 myExe.exe Data.DB                    TDataSet.Resync
007258a0 +0054 myExe.exe Data.DB                    TDataSet.Refresh
01e1705d +0859 myExe.exe DOrder          3318  +164 TfrmDOrder.CompOrder
01e5c4cd +9c91 myExe.exe DOrder         19220 +2287 TfrmDOrder.btnInvoiceClick
005d3c87 +006f myExe.exe Vcl.Controls               TControl.Click
005f84d6 +001e myExe.exe Vcl.StdCtrls               TCustomButton.Click
0077b205 +00a5 myExe.exe Vcl.Buttons      371    +0 TBitBtn.Click
```

Here is the OnCalcFields Code

```
procedure TfrmDOrder.tbDebtorCalcFields(DataSet: TDataset);
begin      
  if not tbDebtor.Active then 
    exit;
  tbDebtorCodeAndName.AsString := tbDebtorCode.AsString + ' - ' + tbDebtorName.AsString;
  tbDebtorAddress.AsString := tbDebtorAddress_1.AsString + ' ' +
    tbDebtorAddress_2.AsString + ' ' + tbDebtorAddress_3.AsString + ' ' + 
    tbDebtorAddress_4.AsString + ' ' + tbDebtorAddress_5.AsString;
end;
```

the code thats causing the onClalcFields to fire in TfrmDOrder.CompOrder is

```
tbDebtor.Refresh;
```

there are a few other OnCalcFields in our system that are having this issue as well

seems that there are a few other people having this issue
http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/forum/questions/1683/access-violation-on-moving-data-into-a-table-field

Update @ 2018-03-22

i haven't been able to reproduce the issue have tried to see if setting either side to an invalid value could force the problem e.g.

```
procedure TfrmDOrder.tbDebtorCalcFields(DataSet: TDataset);
begin      
  if not tbDebtor.Active then 
    exit;
  tbDebtorCodeAndName := nil;
  tbDebtorCodeAndName.AsString := tbDebtorCode.AsString + ' - ' + tbDebtorName.AsString;
  tbDebtorAddress.AsString := tbDebtorAddress_1.AsString + ' ' +
    tbDebtorAddress_2.AsString + ' ' + tbDebtorAddress_3.AsString + ' ' + 
    tbDebtorAddress_4.AsString + ' ' + tbDebtorAddress_5.AsString;
end;
```

or

```
procedure TfrmDOrder.tbDebtorCalcFields(DataSet: TDataset);
var
  aTest : TStringList;
begin
  if not tbDebtor.Active then
    exit;
  tbDebtorCodeAndName.AsString := aTest.Text;
  tbDebtorAddress.AsString := tbDebtorAddress_1.AsString + ' ' +
    tbDebtorAddress_2.AsString + ' ' + tbDebtorAddress_3.AsString + ' ' + 
    tbDebtorAddress_4.AsString + ' ' + tbDebtorAddress_5.AsString;
end;
```

they do raise an access violation but its not at the system.move line

```
008b2a70 +090 OnCalcTest.exe Unit6          394  +5 TForm6.tbDebtorCalcFields
006d8595 +015 OnCalcTest.exe Data.DB                TDataSet.DoOnCalcFields
006d6ca8 +060 OnCalcTest.exe Data.DB                TDataSet.CalculateFields
006d6c0c +048 OnCalcTest.exe Data.DB                TDataSet.GetCalcFields
006d6bba +002 OnCalcTest.exe Data.DB                TDataSet.GetCalcFields
007087e6 +19a OnCalcTest.exe adsdata                TAdsDataSet.GetCurTranslatedRecord
0070895c +088 OnCalcTest.exe adsdata                TAdsDataSet.GetRecord
006d67a0 +078 OnCalcTest.exe Data.DB                TDataSet.GetNextRecord
006d6b2d +015 OnCalcTest.exe Data.DB                TDataSet.GetNextRecords
006d65de +0ea OnCalcTest.exe Data.DB                TDataSet.SetBufferCount
006d6676 +076 OnCalcTest.exe Data.DB                TDataSet.UpdateBufferCount
006d3f68 +028 OnCalcTest.exe Data.DB                TDataSet.DoInternalOpen
006d400a +016 OnCalcTest.exe Data.DB                TDataSet.OpenCursor
0070f228 +000 OnCalcTest.exe adsdata                TAdsDataSet.OpenCursor
006d3ecd +055 OnCalcTest.exe Data.DB                TDataSet.SetActive
008b282e +01a OnCalcTest.exe Unit6          368  +1 TForm6.OpenCloseTables
008b2421 +079 OnCalcTest.exe Unit6          222 +11 TForm6.btnConnectClick
```

Comment: I think it is a pity that both your code and the code in the linked example are written in ways which are unhelpful to indentifying the cause of the problem: your code because it attempts to build the field value all in one long expression, rather than source field by source field, and the linked example because it uses the `dataset[fieldname] := ` construct, which combines many actions into one.

Comment: I agree with @MartynA, you should seperate the code into more lines with nil checks on the fields. Maybe rewrite to using "FindField" and checking if the fields are actually there to avoid running into an access violation.

Comment: Since the AV occurs in `SetAsString` the `tbDebtorCodeAndName` seems to be either nil or in some invalid state.

Comment: i tried setting tbDebtorCodeAndName := nil; before the call above to see if that would reproduce the same issue. it does raise an access violation but the access violation trace is different ill update the question above. and i do agree @MartynA that the code could be done better. but i would like to reproduce the issue before changing it

Comment: It seems to me you have made no serious attempt to provide an MCVE (see SO help section) - even your StringList example is obviously incomplete - so I don't think you are likely to get any useful help here.  I suggest you pursue the issue with the Advantage dataset publishers, if they still support the product.

Answer (score 0):

**This seems to be triggered by a bug in Delphis TDataSet code.**

For me it is reproducable if I choose a very large `DataSize` for the CalcField and an empty AnsiString. A MCVE seems to be available [here](https://www.nexusdb.com/mantis/view.php?id=1937).

We get the same problem with IBObjects and XE4:

```
EAccessViolation at 004071E7, reading from 0DB50000.

[004071E7] System.Move
[00A84F31] IBODataset.TIBODataset.InternalSetFieldData
[00A838A6] IBODataset.TIBODataset.SetFieldData
[007F8952] Data.DB.TDataSet.SetFieldData
[00A83766] IBODataset.TIBODataset.SetFieldData
[00410BFF] System.LocaleCharsFromUnicode
[007E6D2B] Data.DB.TField.SetData
[007E8297] Data.DB.TStringField.SetAsAnsiString
[007E81CB] Data.DB.TStringField.SetAsString
[01678B42] TerminListFrame.TFrameTerminList.QueryTerminCalcFields 
[007FBE71] Data.DB.TDataSet.DoOnCalcFields
[007FA584] Data.DB.TDataSet.CalculateFields
[007FA496] Data.DB.TDataSet.GetCalcFields
[00A8B06E] IBODataset.TIBODataset.GetRecord
[007FA07C] Data.DB.TDataSet.GetNextRecord
[007FA409] Data.DB.TDataSet.GetNextRecords
[007F9EBA] Data.DB.TDataSet.SetBufferCount
[007F9F52] Data.DB.TDataSet.UpdateBufferCount
[007F77E8] Data.DB.TDataSet.DoInternalOpen
[007F788A] Data.DB.TDataSet.OpenCursor
[007F774D] Data.DB.TDataSet.SetActive
```

Evaluating our user bug reports, I think for us about one in one million calls ends up having this access violation.

In [this bugreport for NexusDb](https://www.nexusdb.com/mantis/view.php?id=1937) it is mentioned that the cause of this problem lies in TDataSet code of Delphi versions [XE4 to] XE7:

> This is a bug in Embarcadero's TDataSet code introduced in XE7 (or maybe earlier) as part of the NEXTGEN changes to TDataSet (for Android/iOS support) which has been fixed in XE8.
>
> There is an underlying assumption that the buffer passed to TDataSet.SetFieldData is TField.DataSize in size. Code in Data.DB.pas in XE7 breaks that assumption, which has been fixed in XE8.
>
> The problem only happens with calculated fields, because "normal" fields are stored in the record buffer in a NexusDB specific format, so a mapper function is called to map from the TDataSet/TField specific internal field buffer format into the NexusDB record buffer format, which happens to only read the source up to the null terminator for string fields, while calculated fields are stored in the record buffer in their "native" TDataSet/TField specific format using a simple Move(..., DataSize).

Unfortunally I cannot find the corresponding bug report at Embarcadero. But if you look at the sources you will find:

- `Len := StrLen(PAnsiChar(Value))+1` and `SetLength(Buffer,Len)` in `TStringField.SetAsAnsiString` and
- and with this buffer `SetData(Buffer)` calling `FDataSet.SetFieldData(Field, Buffer, NativeFormat)`
- which (for IBObjects) leads to `TIBODataset.InternalSetFieldData(Field, aBuffer)`
- which finally calls `Move((@aBuffer[0])^, TRecordBuffer(aCalcBuf)[1], Field.DataSize)`

**Given this, I see three workarounds:**

- Upgrade to XE8+
- or modify the source code of your data access components. For IBObjects this would be `Move((@aBuffer[0])^, TRecordBuffer(aCalcBuf)[1], Min(Length(aBuffer), Field.DataSize))`
- write code (eg. helper class) to circumvent the bogus `TDataSet` code. I added [an other answer with code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51059651/2306907) for readablility.

Comment: Other reports for this problem: http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/forum/questions/1683/access-violation-on-moving-data-into-a-table-field and  https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28112687/kbmMemTable-Access-Violation-in-Delphi.html

Comment: Just adding that I've seen this error in XE3 with Advantage 11. Decided to use the class helper in your other answer. We'll see how it works out when we move to prod.

Comment: @FLDelphi We have this in production since 2018 and got no more bug reports so far.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not looking like it's gonna work out for us. It's causing a new AV when opening one of our tables. One thing I noticed is that with the new helper class, the compiler is warning about the method Translate being deprecated. I can't speak to how it works in XE5+, but in XE3 it's unfortunately not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a helper class to circumvent the [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51057775/2306907) with TDataSets `SetAsAnsiString`.

Add this unit:

```
unit Mv.Data.Helper.DB;

interface

uses
    System.SysUtils,
    Data.Db;

type
    TFieldHelper = class helper for TField
        procedure SetAsStringSave(AValue: string);
    end;


implementation

procedure TFieldHelper.SetAsStringSave(AValue: string);
var
    Buf: TValueBuffer;
    S: AnsiString;
begin
    if Self is TStringField then
    begin
        S := AnsiString(AValue);
        //Replace TStringField.SetAsAnsiString because of random access violations:
        //see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49376216/delphi-xe-5-tadstable-random-eaccessviolation-on-oncalcfields/
        SetLength(Buf, DataSize);
        StrLCopy(PAnsiChar(@Buf[0]), PAnsiChar(S), StrLen(PAnsiChar(S)));
        if (Self as TStringField).Transliterate then
          DataSet.Translate(PAnsiChar(@Buf[0]), PAnsiChar(@Buf[0]), True);
        SetData(Buf);
    end
    else
      SetAsString(AValue);
end;


end.
```

And replace

```
procedure TfrmDOrder.tbDebtorCalcFields(DataSet: TDataset);
begin      
    tbDebtorCodeAndName.AsString := tbDebtorCode.AsString; //...
end;
```

with

```
procedure TfrmDOrder.tbDebtorCalcFields(DataSet: TDataset);
begin      
    tbDebtorCodeAndName.SetAsStringSave(tbDebtorCode.AsString); //...
end;
```